# Moving ASP.net membership provider to separate class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I'm building an MVC 2 app with very basic authentication (one user and role to access admin sections). Because some basic forms authentication was built in when I started my project, I just used that. The problem is, I've started moving all of my data access code to a separate project (class library), and I'm not sure how to move the membership provider stuff without breaking everything. I'd rather not leave it with the other code, but I also don't wanna spend hours rolling my own provider when a sufficient one exists.

So, is it possible to move the built-in asp.net membership provider code to a separate class library project? If so, how. If not, what are my options?

Comment: how do you use the Asp.Net Membership? What do you want to move in an other project?

Comment: The base (not empty) MVC 2 project comes with an Account controller, and an AccountModels class, which contains the models, services, and validation code. I want to pull that AccountModels class out and put in in my separate class library. However, it requires System.Web.MVC, and adding that reference would defeat the purpose of this separation (domain shouldn't know about UI implementation).Is there a common way to split up that class? I'm interested in best practices here, since I'm capable of doing it, but want to do it right.

Comment: as for my self I add a reference to System.Web.MVC in my Domain project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For myself I'm using a AuthenticationService class that encapsulate the Membership class, so it's easyer to unit test my controller and also easier to move my class where I want to. In my controller I have a IAuthentificationService that is past in the controller's constructor (from DI). It's also easier if you want to switch from Asp.Net membership to an other "security provider".

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use a class library you'll have to reference System.Web and System.Web.ApplicationServices

Comment: Two years later, but this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in asp.net provider works with just config settings and DB setup. You don't have to write whole lot of code for it. If you are referring to how its methods are called within your code like (getUser() or validateUser() etc..) then you can very well reference the required DLLs in the class library and move the code there.